# Error while creating chatbot using python (Row data)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

So I am creating a chat bot inspired off the tutorials from sentdex yet I ran into an error I can not figure out.

I am using the latest version python

Code for the chat bot:

```
    <i>
      import sqlite3
      import json
      from datetime import datetime

      timeframe = '2007-02'
      sql_transaction = []

      connection = sqlite3.connect('{}.db' .format(timeframe))
      c = connection.cursor()

      def create_table():
      c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_reply
      (parent_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, comment_id TEXT UNIQUE, parent TEXT,
      comment TEXT, subreddit TEXT, unix INT, score INT)""")

      def format_data(date):
      data = data.replace("\n"," newlinechar ").replace("\r"," newlinechar 
      ").replace('"',"'")
      return data

      def find_parent(pid):
      try:
      sql = "SELECT comment FROM parent_reply WHERE comment_id = '{}' 
      LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execture(sql)
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result != None:
            return result [0]
        else: return False
    except Exception as e:
        #print ("find_parent", e)
        return False


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0

    paired_rows = 0

    with open("/home/anonymouz/Desktop/redditdata/{}/RC_{}".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe ), buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            print(row)
            row_counter += 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['created_utc']
            score = row['score']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']

            parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)<i>


And the error I am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anonymouz/Desktop/redditdata/reddit.py", line 44, in <module>
    body = format_data(row['body'])
  File "/home/anonymouz/Desktop/redditdata/reddit.py", line 17, in format_data
    data = data.replace("\n"," newlinechar ").replace("\r"," newlinechar ").replace('"',"'")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
>>>
```

Thank you for anyone who is able to help and isn't rude about it :) 
More clean version of code with correct indents:
    https://pastebin.com/2ifpEQy9

Answer (score 0):

```
def format_data(date):
```

Your parameter is 'date' but your local is 'data'.

Change your parameter name to 'data'

```
def format_data(data):
    data = data.replace("\n"," newlinechar ").replace("\r"," newlinechar 
    ").replace('"',"'")
    return data
```

Comment: Sorry I am not following your answer are you talking about the data.replace?

Comment: You are referencing something that has not been assigned a value yet. By the 'date' parameter inside of ``def format_data(date):`` I assume you meant to type 'data' instead, if you were to use the name 'data' as a parameter you would not get the unbounded reference error, thus the definition should be ``def format_data(data):``